# Speed up PostGIS raster query

Tags: postgis, raster, sql, spatial-index, st-intersects

I have a simple PostGIS table as follows:

```
\d rad;
                                        Table "public.rad"
  Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 rid       | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('rad_rid_seq'::regclass)
 rast      | raster                      |           |          | 
 filename  | text                        |           |          | 
 timestamp | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
Indexes:
    "rad_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (rid)
    "rad_st_convexhull_idx" gist (st_convexhull(rast))
Check constraints:
    "enforce_height_rast" CHECK (st_height(rast) = ANY (ARRAY[50, 38]))
    "enforce_max_extent_rast" CHECK (st_envelope(rast) @ '0103000020E61000000100000005000000BFC1D3FBA65054C0635BE48C898852C0BFC1D3FBA65054C08AC4D8AA6C8752403B22DD8FC75154408AC4D8AA6C8752403B22DD8FC7515440635BE48C898852C0BFC1D3FBA65054C0635BE48C898852C0'::geometry) NOT VALID
    "enforce_nodata_values_rast" CHECK (_raster_constraint_nodata_values(rast) = '{NULL}'::numeric[])
    "enforce_num_bands_rast" CHECK (st_numbands(rast) = 1)
    "enforce_out_db_rast" CHECK (_raster_constraint_out_db(rast) = '{f}'::boolean[])
    "enforce_pixel_types_rast" CHECK (_raster_constraint_pixel_types(rast) = '{32BF}'::text[])
    "enforce_same_alignment_rast" CHECK (st_samealignment(rast, '0100000000307677032F74A53F307677032F74A5BFBFC1D3FBA65054C08AC4D8AA6C87524000000000000000000000000000000000E610000001000100'::raster))
    "enforce_scalex_rast" CHECK (round(st_scalex(rast)::numeric, 10) = round(0.0419020358783481, 10))
    "enforce_scaley_rast" CHECK (round(st_scaley(rast)::numeric, 10) = round(- 0.0419020358783481, 10))
    "enforce_srid_rast" CHECK (st_srid(rast) = 4326)
    "enforce_width_rast" CHECK (st_width(rast) = ANY (ARRAY[50, 29]))
```

Data is loaded using raster2pgsql with the following commands:

```
# first insertion, creates index and constraints
raster2pgsql -d -t 50x50 -C -I -s 4326 file.tif -F rad | psql -U user

# subsequent inserts
raster2pgsql -a -t 50x50 -s 4326 file.tif -F rad | psql -U user
```

As you can see, rasters are tiled into 50x50 tiles; due to tiling, each raster2pgsql invocation creates 5538 lines in the table; since a new raster is imported every 30 minutes, for a full year worth of data the table ends up having 97025760 lines. After importing a raster, the "timestamp" column is filled with the timestamp corresponding to the just-imported raster.

Now I want to query the table to get timeseries corresponding to arbitrary coordinates (365 * 48 = 17520 values, if no timestamp constraints are specified). To that end, I use the following query (for example for coordinates 10, 20):

```
SELECT timestamp, 
  ST_Value(rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(10, 20), 4326)) AS val 
FROM rad 
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(10, 20), 4326))
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

Now the problem is that the query is taking about 3 minutes. Explain shows that the index is being used, and eg https://explain.depesz.com/ tells me that 99% of the query time is spent on the index scan, here is a sample EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
 Sort  (cost=11.32..11.33 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=104116.963..104119.036 rows=17485 loops=1)
   Sort Key: "timestamp"
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1588kB
   ->  Index Scan using rad_st_convexhull_idx on rad  (cost=0.55..11.31 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=46.877..104090.059 rows=17485 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((rast)::geometry && '0101000020E610000000000000000008400000000000002840'::geometry)
         Filter: _st_intersects('0101000020E610000000000000000008400000000000002840'::geometry, rast, NULL::integer)
 Planning Time: 9.583 ms
 Execution Time: 104120.309 ms
(8 rows)
```

(nevermind that it returns only 17485 lines instead of 17520, this is a test table and some data is missing). 
If I re-run the same query immediately after, duration drops to about 7/8 seconds but I suspect that's due to caching somewhere. What I'm worried about is the first run.

What can I do to speed up this query?